# curl request on django working without csrf token

Tags: django, django-csrf

I have a django project running on Heroku, using Django REST framework
I use the following middlewares:

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Here is one of my class-based views :

```
class CommunityMemberView(APIView):
    permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = CommunitySerializer

    def post(self, request, community_id=None):
    """
    add the member identified by 'id'
    to the community 'community_id', if it exists.
    """
    data = request.data
    id = data.get('id')
    account = Account.objects.get(id=id)
    community = Community.objects.get(id=community_id)
    community.add_member(account)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(community, context={'request': request})

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

When I try to do a POST request using curl, and without any csrf token, it works fine, and I don't know why. I don't use any decorator, but if I understand the django doc correctly, I don't need to.

```
 curl -v -H "content:application/json" -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"id":"3"}' https://www.example.com/api/v1/community/2/member/ | python -m json.tool
```

I'm guessing there is an obvious reason, but I can't find it in the django doc nor on Stack Overflow, all the previous questions on a related topic were about why it's not working, not the contrary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming you are using `django-rest-framework`?

DRF views are wrapped w/ `@csrf_excempt` decorator unless you're using `SessionAuthentication`

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I use django-rest-framework, and I'm not using SessionAuthentication for now, so you must be right.